# Single Handle Kitchen Faucet doesnt fully reset after spraying

Tags: repair, kitchen-sink

My faucet normally works like this: when you spray, then turn it off, it goes back to the normal flow when you turn it back on. The problem is, when I turn it back on, it's half spray and half normal.

I don't know the specific terms to be able to search for videos on fixing this problem. Everyone is mostly concerned with water not flowing at all. Any help is appreciated!

[Glacier Bay HD67496-1008D2](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Glacier-Bay-Dylan-Single-Handle-Pull-Down-Kitchen-Faucet-with-TurboSpray-and-FastMount-in-Stainless-Steel-HD67496-1008D2/305188341)

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen to my kitchen sink sprayer, too. The problem was hard water deposits in the valve.

First key is to get soft water. Then the deposits will dissolve back out and free up the valve. So your solution may start in the basement: get a water softener.

Back in the kitchen, push and release the pushbutton many times while the water is on, also change the water from hot to cold and back again several times, to allow possible shrinking/expanding of valve parts, and the deposits in the valve may crunch up enough to break loose. You may need to remove the aerator/sprayer end cover to allow the deposits to spray out.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like it would work. I'll try that next time this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the sprayer from the end of the hose.  Disassemble it as much as practical/possible.  There may be a special tool to remove the screen or aerator, you may have it in your junk drawer.

In general, if there are broken or failed parts inside, either buy a new spray head (not practical for your model but may be for others reading this) or if it has a lifetime warranty (yours doesn't) call the manufacturer's help line.

Manually remove any loose debris and scrape off as much calcium and other deposits as you can from the parts.   Then soak all the parts in vinegar or a store-bought scale remover (sold for kettles, irons, coffee machines).  Then scrape some more and put it back together.

Note: in your case the entire faucet cost $40!  A very reasonable alternative is to just replace the whole thing.

Answer (score -1):

Try spraying the inards of it with wd40. Im fairly certain itll switch like-new again... wd is my go to for everything like that. After spraying make sure to work the switch or buttons back and forth and spray one more time after to be sure its freed of gunk or hard water deposits and should work great.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but If you can get to the "inards" it might be better to use an oil that is edible. WD40 is not edible, and could leave some nasty deposits in this potable water supply device. Maybe vegetable oil might work better, or olive oil? But getting the hard water deposits out of the valve is the key. Seth, you can edit your post and change the WD40 reference to an edible solvent of some sort, then you'd get my vote.

Comment: I'm the downvoter, sorry for the delay.  WD40 does not dissolve calcium, the compound most likely to be clogging the valve, and it is poisonous so using it in a food prep area needs more thought than is suggested here.  Using it for "everything" especially where it has no chance of success and some chance of making people sick is so comical there is [a 60+ year old meme](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=wd40%20duct%20tape%20flow%20chart%20meme&qs=n&form=QBIR&sp=-1&lq=0&pq=wd40%20duct%20tape%20flow%20chart%20meme) for it.

Comment: I really appreciate the follow-up, @jay613 and Triplefault. I might have actually tried to use WD40 at some point, since I don't know any better. I will be careful about what I use in my food prep area and water sources.